# Mac nl only takes lines 2048 chars long

Tags: terminal, command-line

I'm having an issue where the Mac version of `nl` will mark a new line after 2048 characters.  I tried it on Linux, and it doesn't do this.  Any idea why it does on Mac, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

From `man nl`:

> ```
> BUGS
>      Input lines are limited to LINE_MAX (2048) bytes in length.
> ```

To fix, you can either patch the [source](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/text_cmds/text_cmds-47/nl/nl.c) yourself (might need some work) or get the source for the Linux version (which is probably available on any GNU server).

Comment: A bare-bones replacement for `nl` is `awk '{print NR,$0}'`.